# How to get facebook events via event id?

Tags: facebook, events, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

How to get Facebook events via event id?
i wanted to enter a event id to get all of the data, is there any API for this?
or please tell me how to get the events via graph api.

Comment: Please consult the docs _before asking_ … https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the permission: `user_events`

API : `/EVENT_ID`

You can test the same here: [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Comment: At present, I am using the graph API version 2.11, and calling the following URL *https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/188812701672584* where the last parameter is my *eventFbId*. I am getting the following error. ```{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) events management API is deprecated for versions v2.0 and higher",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 12,
    "fbtrace_id": "ECVXFuhf1S+"
  }
}```   any idea what's doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to use Access Token for this...
Check my screenshots:
[Screenshot 1](http://prntscr.com/ikfxfx/direct) 
[& Screenshot 2](http://prntscr.com/ikfxo8/direct)

Comment: Followed the screenshots, same event ID, and the answer is:

"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '188812701672584' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation."

GraphMethodException "code": 100, "error_subcode": 33

I can't get any info about public group / page events for a few days now via Graph API, even can't see the public groups own events with my personal account if I'm not member!

This event is exists and is visible for the public group members. For non-members:

https://imgur.com/a/s7MB9

Any idea?